# align three images side by side in body of website

Tags: html, css

I am having problems with aligning 3 images with text side by side on the homepage of my website. The first two images are aligned and centered perfectly, but the last image won't budge and fall in place. Instead it falls underneath to the left other of the other images on my page. here is the code I am using:

***HTML***

```css
.picture_row li {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
  font-family: "Arial";
}
```

```html
<div class="picture_row">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h3>Custom Web Designs</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250" width="400" height="250" />
      <h5>Represent your business with a Custom Web Design.</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3>Responsive Web Designs</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250" width="400" height="250" />
      <h5>Responisve Web Design allows for better viewing experience on mobile devices</h5>
    </li>

    <li>
      <h3>Affordable Pricing</h3>
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/250" width="300" height="250" />
      <h5>Our competitive pricing lets you stay within your budget while gettting quality custom design work.</h5>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I am having trouble with the third one titled affordable pricing

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: You page needs to be at least 1100px wide in order to have enough room to have the three images display in a single row.  What about smaller screens, do you want a responsive layout?

Comment: yes i want a responsive layout

Answer (score 1):

Add this css to your code
First set the width of container to **100%**

```
.picture_row{
    width:100%;
}
```

Then set each coloumn to around **30%** (you might need to adjust this depending on margin and padding you are giving to your container and child elements)

It will divide li element into 3 container of equal width

```
.picture_row li{
    float:left; 
    display: inline;
    font-family: "heiti sc"
    width:30%;
}
```